# Is my hard drive about to fail?

Tags: hard-drive

I hear some squeaking noises sometimes when I use my computer so I ran smartctl. This is the results:

```
    === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      5953         37922655
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      5953         37922655
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      5953         37922655
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       429         -
# 5  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       429         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       429         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       429         -
```

Is this a bad sign?

Comment: Yes, you are totally fschk'ed. =P

Comment: Oh, * time... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether your HD is failing or not is not clear at all from the output - it could be just one bad sector, which is a common occurrence these days.

Can you please post the full output `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` (change `sda` accordingly if needed)?

Comment: I have since bought a new hard drive. But this was the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 2 hard drives. The newer one (nums 4-7) seem to be alright, but the older one seems to have read failures. This seems to be a bad sign for the old drive. :(.

Comment: Hmm? I only have one drive...unless it counts partitions as drives?

Comment: It can't; it's saying you have 2 drives; because they have totally different lifetimes.

Comment: But I only have one drive...it's a laptop and there is no room for another one. So how is that possible?

Comment: Maybe it could be referring to partitions, do those numbers match when the drive could have been partitioned? If so, perhaps a partition is corrupt?

Comment: I only have 2 partitions: Swap and /. Both were at the same time.